# SQL Server 2008 R2 replication high delivery latency

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactional-replication

I am seeing an unusually high delivery latency between our distributor and subscribers and I do not understand why.

We have in this configuration 3 sql servers using transactional push replication to replicate data from one master server to two reporting servers.

We have 9 publications.  The distribution agent for most publications are showing under 5ms, but one is show as 2000+ms to both subscribers.

The suspect publication has only 4 small articles (tables) that rarely, if ever, change.  I've checked and each table has an primary key.

I've also checked the @status parameter for each article according to the MS KB: [The distribution agent may experience high latency when you configure transactional replication with articles that are configured not to replicate changes as parameterized statements](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2000228).

I'm tempted to start dropping articles to find out if one particular table is the culprit.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can look at?

Comment: Did this just start happening recently, or has it been this way all along? And can you confirm there actually is a performance issue with late deliveries on the subscriber side?

Answer (score 2):

Below script will help you find out how many undistributed commands are there. Also, do you see any errors in sql server or windows logs ? Is it just slow or any failures reported ?

```
SELECT ( CASE 
           WHEN mdh.runstatus = '1' THEN 'Start - ' + CAST( 
                                         mdh.runstatus AS VARCHAR) 
           WHEN mdh.runstatus = '2' THEN 'Succeed - ' + CAST( 
                                         mdh.runstatus AS VARCHAR) 
           WHEN mdh.runstatus = '3' THEN 'InProgress - ' + CAST( 
                                         mdh.runstatus AS VARCHAR) 
           WHEN mdh.runstatus = '4' THEN 'Idle - ' + CAST(mdh.runstatus AS 
                                                          VARCHAR) 
           WHEN mdh.runstatus = '5' THEN 'Retry - ' + CAST( 
                                         mdh.runstatus AS VARCHAR) 
           WHEN mdh.runstatus = '6' THEN 'Fail - ' + CAST(mdh.runstatus AS 
                                                          VARCHAR) 
           ELSE CAST(mdh.runstatus AS VARCHAR) 
         END )                                   [Run Status], 
       mda.subscriber_db                         [Subscriber DB], 
       mda.publication                           [PUB Name], 
       RIGHT(LEFT(mda.name, Len(mda.name) - ( Len(mda.id) + 1 )), 
       Len(LEFT(mda.name, Len(mda.name) - ( Len(mda.id) + 1 ))) - ( 
       10 + Len(mda.publisher_db) + ( CASE 
                                          WHEN mda.publisher_db = 'ALL' THEN 1 
                                          ELSE Len(mda.publication) + 2 
                                        END ) )) [SUBSCRIBER], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), mdh.[time])          [LastSynchronized], 
       und.undelivcmdsindistdb                   [UndistCom], 
       mdh.comments                              [Comments], 
       'select * from distribution.dbo.msrepl_errors (nolock) where id = ' + 
       CAST(mdh.error_id AS VARCHAR(8))          [Query More Info], 
       mdh.xact_seqno                            [SEQ_NO], 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN mda.subscription_type = '0' THEN 'Push' 
           WHEN mda.subscription_type = '1' THEN 'Pull' 
           WHEN mda.subscription_type = '2' THEN 'Anonymous' 
           ELSE CAST(mda.subscription_type AS VARCHAR) 
         END )                                   [SUB Type], 
       mda.publisher_db + ' - ' + CAST(mda.publisher_database_id AS VARCHAR) 
                                                 [Publisher DB], 
       mda.name 
       [Pub - DB - Publication - SUB - AgentID] 
FROM   distribution.dbo.msdistribution_agents mda 
       LEFT JOIN distribution.dbo.msdistribution_history mdh 
         ON mdh.agent_id = mda.id 
       JOIN (SELECT s.agent_id, 
                    maxagentvalue.[time], 
                    SUM(CASE 
                          WHEN xact_seqno > maxagentvalue.maxseq THEN 1 
                          ELSE 0 
                        END) AS undelivcmdsindistdb 
             FROM   distribution.dbo.msrepl_commands t (nolock) 
                    JOIN distribution.dbo.mssubscriptions AS s (nolock) 
                      ON ( t.article_id = s.article_id 
                           AND t.publisher_database_id = s.publisher_database_id 
                         ) 
                    JOIN (SELECT hist.agent_id, 
                                 MAX(hist.[time]) AS [time], 
                                 h.maxseq 
                          FROM   distribution.dbo.msdistribution_history hist ( 
                                 nolock) 
                                 JOIN (SELECT agent_id, 
                                              Isnull(MAX(xact_seqno), 0x0) AS 
                                              maxseq 
                                       FROM 
                                 distribution.dbo.msdistribution_history ( 
                                 nolock) 
                                       GROUP  BY agent_id) AS h 
                                   ON ( hist.agent_id = h.agent_id 
                                        AND h.maxseq = hist.xact_seqno ) 
                          GROUP  BY hist.agent_id, 
                                    h.maxseq) AS maxagentvalue 
                      ON maxagentvalue.agent_id = s.agent_id 
             GROUP  BY s.agent_id, 
                       maxagentvalue.[time]) und 
         ON mda.id = und.agent_id 
            AND und.[time] = mdh.[time]
```

Comment: so i ran the script and the database/publication in question has 0 undistributed commands.  Im using spotlight on sql server to monitor performance and it indicates that "the distribution agent '...' has a latency of 2148.9 seconds. could this just be a false alarm?

Comment: If it has 0 undistributed commands, then there is no data to be replicated. Did you check by launching Replication Monitor to see if you are seeing same latency ? Also this will help you with TSQL Code http://sqlfool.com/2008/11/checking-replication-latency-with-t-sql/

Comment: sql server replication monitor does quite frequently report that the perfomance is critical with latencies of over ... waiting for it to happen again ... 00:02:17 on one or both subscriptions (this occurance was just on one).  This database is mainly a reference database and is rarely written to (maybe once a week) so it doesnt surprise me that there are no transactions to be replicated.  Why though would there be high latency?  I did do a tracer token and from pub to dist the latency is 00:00:04, from dist to sub it is 00:00:03.

Comment: What is your replication setting ? Is it running continuously or every 5 mins, etc ? 
Just another thought ...If this database is rarely written (once a week) why are you using T-Rep ? You do have an option of snapshot replication.
Also, the tracer token latency of 4 sec is not that high which needs a concern ... Did you check your N/W settings or anything has changed on your server that would affect this all of a sudden ?

Comment: this is not all of a sudden.  its just a thorn that i want to get resolved/answered before my boss flips out about it.  T replication is setup to run continously but, now that I think about it, i suppose that we could configure it to run every 5 minutes or so.  We use T replication rather than snapshot replication because, although it doesnt get updated frequently, it does contain tables that are joined for reporting purposes (which pull off of a subscriber) and if the relevant data is not available the report will crash which, considering our clients can see thse reports is not good.

Comment: Thanks ! Unless there is a business need, there is no need for Replication to run continuously. Your case makes sense to schedule it to run every 5 mins or 15 - 30 mins. Did you check the n/w if packets are being dropped using tracert or ping ... and probably with your n/w team to see if there is any change in the n/w ?